# Java do not keep request idle

Tags: java, spring, servlets, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure Web app (app services) for a java (java 8) application (.war). It uses spring 4 and JSP.

There are certain requests which take more than 4-5 minutes to send the response.

There is a limitation of Azure app service that if a request does not get any response in 230 sec, it throws request timeout, and we cannot update this timeout duration.

I would like to know if there is a way to make sure that the request does not remain idle while the response is still being prepared (say once every 3 minutes if the response is not sent yet).

Comment: I would have a `/request` endpoint which starts the request running in a background thread, and a `/status` endpoint which can be polled by the client (or specify a callback URL in the request if that suits your architecture better)

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you can do the request asynchronously，send the request and response `202`. Then client check the work of the request and return `200` when it's done.

You can also move your code to [azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) which can execute longer than app service. Even if you do not use durable function, just use normal function with consumption plan, it can [set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout) the timeout to 10 mins maximum which can meet your 4-5 minutes requirement.